# Array to JSON Array of Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Maping an Object `AppData` like

```
heatPoints = AppData.map(function (point) {
        return [point.Latitude, point.Longitude];
});
```

returns

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(heatPoints));
```

> [[49.2898,-123.1364],[49.2752,-88.150209833],[49.2286,-123.1515]]

but I need to load them into JSON `Points` as an array of JSON String like:

```
var schoolPoints = {
                    "Points": [
                               {"latitude":49.2898,"longitude":-123.1364},
                               {"latitude":49.2752,"longitude":-123.0719},
                               {"latitude":49.2286,"longitude":-123.1515}
                      ]
                    };
```

can you please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your map to return an object instead of an array, like so:

```
heatPoints = AppData.map(function (point) {
    return {
        "latitude": point.Latitude, 
        "longitude": point.Longitude 
    };
});
```

Then you can additionally set it as a property to a variable in order to get the specific JSON you requested:

```
heatPoints = {"Points": heatPoints};
```

Which will result in the exact JSON that you requested.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` is used to reformat the items. You can use it like the following.

```
heatPoints = {
    "Points": AppData.map(function (point) {
        return { 
            "latitude"  : point.Latitude, 
            "longitude" : point.Longitude
        };
     })
};
```